# Finding the reason for a UAC elevation in Windows 7

Tags: windows, logging, windows-7, uac

I've inherited maintenance of an application that, when it runs, occasionally causes the UAC admin elevation (Do-you-wish-to-allow-this?) dialog to appear. To me, the obvious first thing to try is "switch on UAC logging", re-run the application to make the dialog appear, then find the entry in the log that says, for example, "2013-11-23-19:10:03 [MyApplication] attempted to write registry entry [MyRegistryKey]. Requires admin authorization", then take steps to resolve things so the dialog doesn't surface when the application is being used.

However, some people posted questions about UAC logging in 2008/09, in relation to Vista, and the answer was something like "UAC doesn't log, but that would be a great feature for a future release". Was UAC logging ever implemented, either in Windows 7 or as a patch release? If not, is there an alternative technique that is commonly used?

Comment: Are you the developer of this application?  If not, you are in the wrong place.  SuperUser answers computer administration questions that aren't about programming.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I'm looking at this from a developer perspective, yes. I'm unfamiliar with the application but if I know what's going wrong then I can access the code and possibly home in on a solution straight away. Is that what you meant?

Comment: So you are going to rebuild the application from source?  Yes, that is what matters, not where you got the code but that you are making code changes and not, for example, simply finding the offending registry entry and changing its permissions.

Comment: It must be making an out-of-process call, because elevation has to be done before a process is launched.  Once the process exists, it's permanently associated with its login token that controls privileges, including UAC elevation level.

Comment: OK, thanks. That makes sense. If I could find out from a log record some details about an out-of-process call then that would make my task somewhat more efficient. My current investigation might be a one-off, but I can see there being other "elevation" cases like this for me in the future.

Comment: Have you already tried running in a debugger, and when you get the prompt instead of answering it, hit the debugger BREAK command and check your call stack?  Fact is, there's nothing for UAC to log.  There's an operation that failed with access denied, and there's a later attempt to launch an elevated program, but as far as Windows is concerned there is nothing to connect the two.

Comment: Using the debugger is a fallback position, I know. However the problem was reported in pre-production, and my feeling was that logging would be a sensible first step because there may well be differences between the security and environment setup in pre-production and the setup on a developer machine.

In terms of what you just said, I am interested in the "operation that failed with access denied" and not so much with the attempt to launch an elevated program. If I change the program (or the runtime envronment, or both) so that it no longer causes the "access denied" then problem solved.

Comment: Thinking this through, Ben, are you saying that my "UAC logging" is the same thing as turning on standard security event logging, something akin to using this : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731826.aspx ?

Comment: Yes, if you're trying to find access denied errors on some OS object, then auditing is your friend.  So is the System Internals (now part of the Microsoft Technet division) Process Monitor tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> find the entry in the log that says, for example, "2013-11-23-19:10:03 [MyApplication] attempted to write registry entry [MyRegistryKey]. Requires admin authorization"

UAC does not work like that. Windows does not watch an application, and based on the activity decide that it should run elevated next time.

Windows 7 mostly behaves the same as Windows XP in this regard. If your app is running as a standard user, tries to write to:

```
HKLM\Software\Cotoso\Litware
```

your application will get an `Access Denied` error message.

## Unless File and Registry Virtualization is enabled for buggy apps

Unfortunately, most applications are poorly written. Most applications, when run as a standard user on Windows 2000 or Windows XP, crash horribly. Since 1999, as part of the Windows Logo Requirements, Microsoft has required developers to test their applications while running as a standard user. Almost nobody ever does.

That is why, starting with Windows Vista, Microsoft added a feature that lets your buggy application **think** it successfully wrote to **HKLM**, or **Program Files**. If a write fails, which *would* have succeeded if the user was an administrator, Windows will reissue the write operation, except this time redirect it someplace that will succeed. For example:

```
writes to 
   HKLM\Software
are redirected to 
   HKCU\<User SID>_Classes\VirtualStore\Machine\Software

writes to 
   C:\Program Files
are redirected to 
   C:\Users\Westwell\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files
```

Neither of these redirection mechanisms will cause your application to be elevated on next launch. Both of these features are temporary compatibility hacks. You can inform Windows that you wrote your application correctly, opt-out of file and registry virtualzation, by adding a `requestedExecutionLevel` of `asInvoker` to your application's assembly manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
   <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="X86" name="client" type="win32"/> 

   <description>Westwell Contoso</description> 

   <!-- Disable file and registry virtualization -->
   <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
      <security>
         <requestedPrivileges>
            <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
         </requestedPrivileges>
      </security>
   </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Now only eliminates the side-discussion of why sometimes writes can succeed, even when the user is a standard user.

## When does UAC Elevation happen

There are five reasons why an application might prompt to elevate on launch:

1. You manifested that your application needs to be run as an administrator.

   If you app needs to be run as an administrator, and cannot perform any useful functionality without being an administrator, then you can manifest your application as `requireAdministrator` (rather than `asInvoker`):

   ```
   <description>Westwell Contoso</description> 

   <!-- Disable file and registry virtualization -->
   <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
      <security>
         <requestedPrivileges>
            <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
         </requestedPrivileges>
      </security>
   </trustInfo>
   ```

   If this were the case, then the application would always run as an administrator. So that's not it.
2. You manifested that your application be run as administrator **only if** the user actually is an administrator.

   Applications like **RegEdit** can run fine as a standard user, they do not require elevation. But if the user is actually an Administrator RegEdit can prompt to elevate to the user's full admin privelages. This done by marking your application as `highestAvailable` (rather than `asInvoker` or `requireAdministrator`):

   ```
   <description>Westwell Contoso</description> 

   <!-- Disable file and registry virtualization -->
   <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
      <security>
         <requestedPrivileges>
            <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
         </requestedPrivileges>
      </security>
   </trustInfo>
   ```

   If this were the case, your app would prompt for elevation for admins, but not prompt for standard users. This cannot be the cause because your application has no manifest.
3. Compatibilty option marked the application as **Run as administrator**.

   The user can choose to mark an application so that it should prompt for elevation:

   [image]

   The state of this checkbox (and the other checkboxes) is stored in the registry:

   ```
   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers
   ```

   and for *"all users"* under:

   ```
   HKLM\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers
   ```

   [image]

   This option can be per-user, or per-machine. So it's possible some users will see an elevation prompt, and others will not. This could be a source of your problem.
4. [Installer detection heuristics](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709628%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

   By default, Windows will attempt to recognize that an application is probably an installer (e.g. `setup.exe`, `install.exe`, `update.exe`) and prompt the user to elevate. This feature can be disabled through group policy, the policy name is [**User Account Control: Detect application installations and prompt for elevation**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd851376.aspx).

## The Easy Fix

The easy fix is to simply mark your application `asInvoker`. That will disable heuristics.

After that, it must be a compability setting on the machine (AppCompatFlags in HKCU or HKLM).

## Bonus Reading

- [Registry Virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [User Account Control Data Redirection](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2009/08/04/user-account-control-data-redirection.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, Iain. I eventually got to the bottom of this. Your full list did include the correct answer to this problem ("UAC heuristics" led Windows to think the application was an installer), so I'm marking this as the answer. I'm also adding more detail in a separate answer, in case this is useful to others.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the problem eventually. Here is what happened.

1) I tried Ben's suggestion of using the sysinternals tools. The tools that seemed useful were

DependencyWalker
ProcessExplorer
ProcessMonitor

They each provide a lot of information about what is going on, and I can see that these will need to be the first port of call for many, if not most, Windows problems. However, in my case I double clicked the app and got the UAC userid/password dialog but then found that not much information had been written by the tools up to the point the dialog was surfaced.

It also looked like it would be useful to digest the contents of the Microsoft Press Windows Internals books when attempting to troubleshoot problems with UAC.

2) I tried using the Application Compatibility Toolkit, but it showed no issues with the program either on XP (where it worked) or Windows 7 (both with standard user, which surfaced the UAC dialog and admin user, which worked)

3) I then tried painstakingly recreating the app from scratch, starting with an empty project and then copying in files and settings bit by bit. At each stage, I checked whether the app would launch without surfacing the UAC dialog.

Eventually I applied a change and this caused the UAC dialog to surface. This was a VB6 app and I changed the "application title" and the "product name" in the dialog Project, Properties, Make. The previous (failing) value of each field was "ApplicationName Update". To make the app work without UAC elevation, what I had to do was remove the word "Update".

As Ian suggested above, it looks like the UAC heuristics were being applied, and to values within the exe. I see that the Windows Internals book does talk about scanning for byte sequences in the exe when deciding whether to elevate.

4) So in summary, the approach that worked for me was to reassemble the app bit by bit and see at what stage the UAC dialog is triggered. Once this happens, knowledge of the four reasons given by Ian in the previous answer become important.

5) I should point out that I have fixed the problem by removing the thing that was being flagged in the heuristics, but didn't consider the alternative suggested by Ian: "asInvoker". It could be that this is the best thing to try rather than spending time inside the (legacy) app fixing problems.